# Password Protect wp-content?

Tags: plugins, password

We have a password protected blog, so only users with the password can see the text on the posts - but each image we add to the blog post generate URLs which can then be accessed by anyone who knows the link and listed in Google.

Is there anyway of password protecting certain images in WordPress?

Comment: Are you hosting your WordPress yourself? If so, you could password protect the folder on your server/using the host login. For STRATO, for example, it's possible to set passwords in the customer login in the security section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password protecting the wp-content maybe not a good idea and may break your site interface.
If you want the images are not displayed in google search
Create a Robot.txt file in your root directory in hosting and add the code below.

```
   User-agent: *
   Disallow: /wp-admin/
   Disallow: /wp-content/

  or below if you want to not specific images 

   User-agent: Googlebot-Image
   Disallow: /images/yourImageName.jpg #yourImageName.jpg image for Googlebot 
   specifically.
```

1. [Or Use this plugin and add below code in Settings>Phpinserter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/)

> Blockquote

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
if ( is_page( 'your_page_name' ) ) {
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
}} );

your specific page will be not index by Google
```

Or you can pick plugin of your choice from here. It is a preferable method but you have to find some free **plugins for content restriction**.

[Some plugins for restriciting page contents](https://www.wpexplorer.com/restrict-content-member-wordpress/)